# The Best Way to Handle Big File Uploads in Azure

Tags: azure, backgroundworker, azure-worker-roles, worker, azure-webjobs

We are having a VM hosting our web application where its users upload big files to their profiles -mainly they are 3d models- via the Web API of the web app.

What I'm looking to do is to find a way to handle these long running uploading jobs/process efficiently to some place rather than the VM where I'm hosting the application.

I know there are some Azure methods but I want to make it correct. Which is the most efficient way to do that ? Worker Role, a web page running a scripts to upload it to storage or Web Jobs over a queue maybe ?

The function which uploads the file also is having some other processes like generating thumbnails, storing the data to sql and etc.

Comment: Are you uploading the files to Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Currently yes. But my concern is to move this process to some another place to not to tire the vm.

Comment: You can upload the File to Blobs using the Web API. Any further processing can be offloaded to a WebJob. If you use the WebJobs SDK you can trigger a function when a new File is uploaded to a blob container. The function can do the processing such as generating thunbnails etc.

Comment: If you want to process the File as soon as it is uploaded to the blob container then send a message on a queue. if you do not care about instant processing, then you can just use BlobTrigger

Comment: I'll post my code here as an answer as soon as I do a stable solution. Currently I'm running a console app to make the works on vm